Serilog ignoring overrides
I am setting an override in the appsettings.json like this:
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics": "Warning"

However, I'm still getting logged events at the Information level where RenderedMessage and MessageTemplate is:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HttpRequestIn

and the SourceContext is empty. Usually this is namespace.
The current appsettings.json is as follows:
"Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "Override": {
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics": "Warning",
        }
    }
}

So if the override is not working, how can I ignore these events?
EDIT
I currently added the following to exclude specific events:
"Using": [
  "Serilog.Sinks.Http",
  "Serilog.Expressions"
],
"Filter": [
  {
    "Name": "ByExcluding",
    "Args": {
      "expression": "StartsWith(@m, 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HttpRequestIn')"
    }
  }
]

However, the overrides should work and there is no need to use a filter.

Could you please tell me how you configure the serilog? Is there any other config inside your application? and the SourceContext is empty could you please share some related logs to let me check?

Serilog does not use the default logging configuration section, try moving the setup to Serilog -> MinimumLevel -> Override:
"Serilog": {
  "MinimumLevel": {
     "Default": "Information",
        "Override": {
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics": "Warning"
   }
},

Also check out:

Serilog.Settings.Configuration docs how to configure it from the configuration
The MinimumLevel, LevelSwitches, overrides and dynamic reload section of the docs.
How to override Root section name used by Serilog, but note it has different structure then the default one.
Serilog integration with ASP.NET Core


That is what I have. I updated my question.

@IvanDebono can you please provide a  full [mre] with the setup, etc.?
